# Selenium pagination problem: First and last pages are skipped when scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pagination

I am using the code below to try to scrape product data from 90 pages; however the data from the first and last pages are missing in the list object when complete. Due to the nature of the website I cannot use scrapy or beautiful soup, so I am trying to navigate page by page with Selenium web driver. I have tried adjusting the number_of_pages to the actual number pages +1, which still skipped the first & last pages. I have also tried to set the page_to_start_clicking to 0 which produces a timeout error. Unfortunately I cannot share more about the source because of the authentication. Thank you in advanced for the help!

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ResultsPerPageBottom > nav > span.next'))).click() # next button

number_of_pages = 90 # PROBLEM 1st & last pages missed
page_to_start_clicking = 1 # error if 0 

# range set from 0; skips 1st and last page
for i in range(0, 90):
    time.sleep(2)
    for ele in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.srp-item-body'):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
        print(ele.text)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, f"{page_to_start_clicking}"))).click()
    page_to_start_clicking = page_to_start_clicking + 1
```

Comment: With a little bit twisted logic the scrapping may become easier. First scrap then click on **Next** till the element is clickable.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. I successfully scraped the first page, but for some reasons it stops somewhere randomly mid way through scraping. The error is: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

As a shorthand solution I just ran same code again in the next cell and it scraped the rest. It would be nice to get it all together though.

Comment: I'd happily try to solve _`StaleElementReferenceException`_ rather missing out the first and the last page.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code from the solution described in the comments.

```
# Scrape & pagination
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

number_of_pages = 91 

listings = []
for i in range(0, 91):
    time.sleep(2)
    for ele in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.srp-item-body'):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
        listings.append(ele.text)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ResultsPerPageBottom > nav > span.next'))).click()
```